# Accessing and storing the values of multiple textfields that have the same name and ID

Tags: javascript, html

So I am developing a website that automatically generates MLA citations based on user input (website: http://www.citethat.net/) and I have a section where you can add more text fields so you can add more contributors to the citation. I am using this code to generate the new textfields (one for first name, the other for the last name).

```
  function addInput1(divName) {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.setAttribute("id", "divider")
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]' class='textFields' placeholder='First Name' class='textField' id='contributor1'>";
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
  }

  function addInput2(divName) {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.setAttribute("id", "child")
    newdiv.innerHTML = "<br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]' class='textFields' placeholder='Last Name' class='textField' id='contributor2'>";
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
  }
```

And this code is being triggered in the HTML by this button:

```
<input type="button" value="Add a contributor" onClick="addInput1('row1'); addInput2('row2');" class="button">
```

The issue that I am facing is that when I try to retrieve the values with this function:

```
function retrieve(id) {
    var txtbox = document.getElementById(id);
    var value = txtbox.value;
    alert(value);
}
```

It only returns the value of the first generated text field and not all of them at once.

Comment: multiple elements can't (should not) have the same ID in html

Comment: The function name gives it away: ```getElementById``` is singular, ```getElementsByClassName``` is plural. Try using the latter - but also try generating unique IDs to conform to HTML standards.

Comment: @Owen Thanks for the response, I am a little new to javascript and HTML, could you give me an example on how I would go about generating the unique IDs?

Comment: Sure - you can concatenate strings with `+`. If you only need to ensure they are unique you could use `newdiv.setAttribute("id", "child"+(new Date()).getTime())`. Another way is to have a counter with the index of the last node added and append that.